# Clicking outside a button with dropdown menu should close the menu, but clicks in Sigma div don't close it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, sigma.js

In my webpage, I have a jQuery UI button and menu combo:

```
$("#changeTemplateMenuBtn").button().click(function() {
  let menu = $('#template-node-type-menu');
  menu.show().position({
    my: 'left bottom',
    at: 'left top',
    of: this,
  });
  $(document).one('click', function() {
    menu.hide();
  });
  return false;
});
```

The intended behavior is that when `changeTemplateMenuBtn` is clicked, `template-node-type-menu` should appear, and when a click outside of the button is registered, the menu should hide. However, I also have a Sigma.js chart div; clicks outside the button and outside the Sigma div hide the menu as intended, but clicks outside the button but inside the Sigma div do not hide the button. I suspect that the Sigma instance is capturing the clicks and preventing them from reaching the `$(document).one('click')` handler, but in reading the Sigma docs I don't understand how to pass these click events through in the appropriate cases if that is indeed what's happening.